# Who is the rightful ruler?

Tags: code-golf, json

Who will rule the realm?

You are given a family tree which contains: name, sex, date of birth, date of death and a list of heirs, for each family member. You may use any convenient (nested) list format to represent the tree. The following examples will use JSON. Determine who will rule the realm and in which order.
The succession rules are the following:

1. When a king dies the realm goes to its oldest legit male child.
2. If there is none it passes to the oldest legit female child.
3. In case the king had no heirs the realm goes to the oldest legit king's brother
4. If there are no male brothers the realm will go to the oldest legit king's sister
5. If all legit relatives are dead the realm goes to the closest bastard, applying the above rules
6. If no legit nor bastard relatives are alive print `LINE EXTINCT`

We define a legit son as one who has the same "house" name as its father.

Examples:

Input
`{}`

Output
`LINE EXTINCT`

Input

```
{
    "name" : "Maegor",
    "house" : "Targaryen",
    "birth" : 12,
    "death" : 48,
    "sex" : "male",
    "heirs" : []
}
```

Output `12-48: Maegor, LINE EXTINCT`

Input

```
{
    "name" : "Jaehaerys",
    "house" : "Targaryen",
    "birth" : 34,
    "death" : 103,
    "sex" : "male",
    "heirs" : [
        {
        "name" : "Viserys",
        "house" : "Targaryen",
        "birth" : 77,
        "death" : 129,
        "sex" : "male",
        "heirs" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

Output `34-103: Jaehaerys, 103-129: Viserys, LINE EXTINCT`

Input

```
{
        "name" : "Eddard",
        "house" : "Stark",
        "birth" : 263,
        "death" : 299,
        "sex" : "male",
        "heirs" : [
            {
            "name" : "Robb",
            "house" : "Stark",
            "birth" : 283,
            "death" : 300,
            "sex" : "male",
            "heirs" : []
            },
            {
             "name" : "Jon",
             "house" : "Snow",
             "birth" : 284,
             "death" : 384,
             "sex" : "male",
             "heirs" : []
            },
            {
             "name" : "Sansa",
             "house" : "Stark",
             "birth" : 286,
             "death" : 320,
             "sex" : "female",
             "heirs" : []
            },
            {
             "name" : "Arya",
             "house" : "Stark",
             "birth" : 289,
             "death" : 350,
             "sex" : "female",
             "heirs" : []
            },

            {
             "name" : "Brann",
             "house" : "Stark",
             "birth" : 290,
             "death" : 315,
             "sex" : "male",
             "heirs" : []
            },
            {
             "name" : "Rickon",
             "house" : "Stark",
             "birth" : 295,
             "death" : 319,
             "sex" : "male",
             "heirs" : []
            }

        ]
    }
```

Output: `263-299: Eddard, 299-300: Robb, 300-315: Brann, 315-319: Rickon, 319-320: Sansa, 320-350: Arya, 350-384: Jon, LINE EXTINCT`

Note that the output can be formatted in any way you wish, its only requirements is that it contains the time of reign and the name of the reigning king during those years.
I've used kings from the ASOIAF as demonstrative example, however the code needs to be valid for all input.

You may assume that no twins will be born.

This is a code golf challenge, so the shortest code in bytes wins

Good luck!!!

Comment: How are "bastards" represented?

Comment: In itself they are not indicated as an attribute, one would need to check if their family name is different from the father's.

Comment: @WizardOfMenlo So is their house name their family name?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI yes

Comment: Also, are we allowed to use JSON processing libraries (such as Python's json module?)

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I think it's good, so you can abstract the problem

Comment: @WizardOfMenlo In your last example, shouldn't Arya follow Robb? I see that you put Brann after Robb, but Arya is older than Brann (as per your JSON, both are males).

Comment: No because arya is a girl (even if in the book the mistake is common)

Comment: Ok, so I guess you should correct the JSON then, right?

Comment: @Razvan I forgot to update the json sorry, I copy and pasted it too quick

Comment: Also: after Sansa shouldn't there be Arya? (because she is family and Jon is bastard). And after Brann shouldn't there be Rickon? (as he is male and is still alive). I see it like this: 263-299: Eddard, 299-300: Robb, 300-315: Brann, 315-319: Rickon, 319-320: Sansa, 320-350: Arya, 350-384: Jon, LINE EXTINCT

Comment: @Razvan you're right, my mind failed me :)

Comment: @Celeo I think it's my wording, it should be the king's brother/sister, I'll change it now (I've just checked and discovered sibling means something completely different to what I thought)

Comment: Your second example shows Maegor where I believe it should be Jaehaerys.

Comment: @Geobits you're 100% right

Comment: Does this have to work with infinite amounts of heirs? For example Robb has a son, would it go to John or Robb's son?

Comment: @SpeedyNinja yes, if Rood had a son/daughter the realm would go to the son/daughter , and if this heir had a heir of its own the realm would go down that line

Comment: @WizardOfMenlo Point 3 is a bit unclear - `In case the king had no sons the realm goes to the oldest legit king's brother`. It seems to conflict with point 2(If no legit son, then oldest legit daughter is crowned). Do you mean `heirs` instead of `sons` in point 3?

Comment: @kamehameha yes, I'll edit it now

Comment: What about aunts/uncles of the current ruler?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: @WizardOfMenlo Can you provide an example case where it will reach the king's brother/sister's realm?

Answer (score 6):

### PHP, 664 bytes

I'm not sure if 664 bytes fit for code golfing, but here it is:

```php
$k=json_decode($argv[1]);$s=[];$f='array_shift';$r='heirs';$e='death';$y='year';function s
($k,&$e){uasort($e,function($a,$b)use($k){$c=$a->{$h='house'};$d=$b->$h;$e=$k->$h;if($c==$e
&&$d!=$e)return-1;elseif($c!=$e&&$d==$e)return 1;elseif($a->sex<$b->sex)return 1;elseif($a
->sex>$b->sex)return -1;else return$a->birth-$b->birth;});}function d(&$e,$y){foreach($e 
as$i=>$h)if($h->death<=$y)unset($e[$i]);};($x=(array)$k)&&$k->$y=$k->birth;$l=[];while($x)
{$l[]=$k;$z=$k->$e;s($k,$k->$r);d($k->$r,$k->$e);if($k->$r){$s=$k->$r;$k=$f($s);}else{s($k
,$s);d($s,$k->$e);$k=$f($s);}if(!$k)break;$k->$y=$z;}foreach($l as$k)
echo"{$k->$y}-{$k->$e}: $k->name, ";echo"LINE EXTINCT";
```

It receives the JSON string input as the first command line argument.

The algorithm follows the steps described in the challenge (starts from the king, then sorts the heirs and then the siblings to find the next king).

[Demo](http://ideone.com/YxXisC)

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: `while` loop are prohibited when golfing in PHP :).

Comment: I think there is a mistake, I've tested it here and it [link](http://ideone.com/DHVImP) goes correctly down the line, however after it doesn't go back up to give Jon Snow it's rightful throne

Comment: It's not a mistake. It actually follows the rules that were defined in the challange. As you can see, the last king is Tyrion which is the son of Arya. This means that the next king should be among the heirs of Tyrion or one of his brothers. But he has no brothers, nor heirs. Please note that, as per the JSON in your example, Jon Snow is the uncle of Tyrion.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my fanboysm got the best of me

Comment: You could golf a bit if you replace fields `death`, `sex` etc. with shorter names. The OP allowed any format you like, so one could even try with a format given by the "var_export" function

Comment: Storing readable version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVKxTsMwEN39FWl1amIpGVhxXQbEgISYGJCqCrnJBYeEpLITaIjy7eVsU0BITH6@e3nP9y4HfTid1lcHfWBQyxfbtU8F5l2BCSjz/La92HHBwMrtjo5SxsoYNT5ZXZV9TBUjY42VsQ6jjAtUvXZ4lPGIyhAshzbvq66NbAJ1ugLkExuU7UyfAKbnLrmlsOeDJd@aT5BLUNlmAk36HVXjmUQLCftsA9p7QR1gVSbEloCrFRQLOrnBfjBtdiEYNhZ9f/HVlz/96FefrCwe106dzn8Jmz@Es0UU7o61r0yvM8fzSMxczD8RFAnNn8JIEZSdQZVryiBSFipJs3DnpLOND3EtiTa0Fl1MW6jcGiiDBI4y8TvglBON5FIYfRjBkEHjd/Wuq4ayPJIVNNsdMaj1EVJDwfwy/MWQcJEEGCrIQ6qhO9HyAxT0gwDVrZvJzT05FZa6AinY769/80hoQS/d07S1OL/2w4VyDqBxAdScYa675RQocxYAzpeRA616xTRaCs@5u72/iW4eH27vrx@Wgp1Onw)

Answer (score 5):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>429..410</s> 392bytes

```
def s(x;y):sort_by(.sex,-.birth)[]|select(.death>x.death and(.house==x.house|y));def i:index([[.[1:][]|select(.!=[])][0]]);def b(z;x;y):[.[i+z][:z+length-1]|s(x;y)];def h(x;y):[x.heirs|s(x;y)];[[],[],[],[],sort_by(-.birth)?]|until(i|not;.[i][-1]as$r|[.[0]+[$r+{t:(.[0][-1].death//$r.birth)}],h($r;.),h($r;not),b(0;$r;.),b(i%2;$r;not)])|[.[0][]|"\(.t)-\(.death):\(.name)"]+["LINE EXTINCT"]|.[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZLRbtMwFIbveYoQFclW0yxt6UQSFQSoF0NoF9sukLwj5CweMesc4XgibdNnL47TtUlGClIHViTb5z8@5//sfP@x2cTs1spQHi5wkKVSfY0WyM1Y7gzciEuVYAJFxubsRiE3ZlQlb/NqtqiIkZukDxmbTvNqUSwwDsuCPOAiZjkixCXDAGo1Xk4JYCAeQJUZoWVomutM3l8CCZb9ORPfVDIY6lPGGJjMpDJJdC/GZbbTCAFn9z0iPLp/B8WDUHyOeCFSFeoeQHRhmvVkoTt60Cc92V@pAJWbUqroTk56cltiDU6CejJ0cTXrOtiJkBdWsQjxV6NwGwdcVdXA9jVyFR5cb68NB3ol6D3Dtu5pfz47n1mzL1dn5x@vbChcApsNWb2wtsMuM20rsOxZHFMZ285eMjdttEtF5V1dMoZLaXQ6roWNARP2/VpYv7Ipc0/nrNGgvN5SIbtYOVaN3d7hRRpFteN/8Njy@WbcknZex57Xkjr8tjxDQ1g7BxhqEJ9S0SrZgBDpzydyDeJ1W9tTPNUOYBzPcUlFRg@R/OY5Giin3Sgjrwvllv0TmPdycRSL380yeUaWv4P5IKkQR9D4XjfNcPJff7ILfnOXHsUyOcDiPw/L/lkqYQ2/AA)

**Explanation:**

```
def s(x;y):sort_by(.sex,-.birth)[]                          #Function: sorts by sex lexicographically, then by birth date in descending order [youngest female -> oldest male]
            |select(                                        and selects those who
                .death > x.death                            did not die before the previous ruler
                and (.house == x.house|y)                   and have the same house (if y := not, selects those with a different house)
            );                                              
def i:index([[.[1:][]|select(.!=[])][0]]);                  #Function: returns index of the first not-empty array (ignoring first array)
def b(z;x;y):[.[i+z][:z+length-1]|s(x;y)];                  #Function: drops the last z (0 or 1) elements of the (i+z)th array and applies s on the resulting array
def h(x;y):[x.heirs|s(x;y)];                                #Function: takes the heirs of x and applies s
                                                            
[                                                           An array containing five bins:
    [],                                                         0. Result
    [],                                                         1. Heirs from same house
    [],                                                         2. Heirs from another house
    [],                                                         3. Siblings from same house
    sort_by(-.birth)?                                           4. Siblings from another house (initial: sorted input (The ? is necessary for empty inputs)) 
                                                            
|until(                                                     Until
        i|not                                               there is no such index i
    ;                                                       
        .[i][-1]as$r                                        set the last element of the ith array as the current ruler
        |[                                                  Update the array:
            .[0]+[$r+{t:(.[0][-1].death//$r.birth)}],       Add the current ruler + new attribute (the beginning time of reign) to the result array
            h($r;.),                                        Heirs from same house
            h($r;not),                                      Heirs from another house
            b(0;$r;.),                                      Siblings from same house
            b(i%2;$r;not)                                   If the ruler is heir from the same house as the previous one, store the heirs from a different house here 
                                                            else siblings from a different house
        ]                                                   
)                                                           
|                                                           
    [                                                       
        .[0][]                                              Takes the result array
        |"\(.t)-\(.death):\(.name)"                         Writes time of reign and ruler
    ]                                                       
    +["LINE EXTINCT"]                                       Writes "LINE EXTINCT"
|.[]                                                        Prints on seperated lines
```

Comment: amazing! I chickened out of trying to do this since the spec was a bit wordy. very nicely done!

Comment: @Razetime thank you very much!

Comment: You can save 53 bytes by using one character names for the keys, `"N": "Eddard", "H" : "Stark"...`

Comment: @JohanduToit can I? It says I can choose the data format but nothing about the content or even the naming of the keys.

Comment: This part is a bit vague: You may use any convenient(nested) list format to represent the tree. I'm assuming that something like this will also be valid input [TIO](https://tio.run/##bc4/D4IwEAXw3U/RMNcEqKiNcdDExRFG0uGgDEDSmoNg/PT1AEnkzw0vN/zy8irooMmxfLV7Y3XhnOsAWYtFwa4s3TG61HtoDag9zrykBazpCY@CQkrOfP5jI41tls3gmaDw/REqxf/s05qBGvse5IFkH2uZgGlgXnsiHJIMVviGn4WlmSLatHcEY2ZYkhNBtLUiLvPaLnTUaznpAU@pLu4L)

Comment: @JohanduToit sounds good. Thanks for the tip! I will change it later.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>294</s> <s>248</s> <s>244</s> 245 bytes

```javascript
t=>{for(s(t),o(t.b,t);t;)o(t.d,t=n(t,0))}
s=(r,p)=>r.c.sort((a,b)=>a.s-b.s||a.b-b.b,r.g=p?(r.u=p.h!=r.h,p.c):[]).map(h=>s(h,r))
n=(k,b,j)=>[...k.c,...k.g].map(h=>j=j||h.u==b&h.d>k.d&&h)&&j||b?j:n(k,1)
o=(f,h)=>alert(h?[f,h.d,h.n]:'LINE EXTINCT')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdJBT9swFAfwez6Fl0OwNfOUAt2WVk61TT0wTRyAw6QqEnaS1iSdHdkeMLX97J0dGi4rG77k/6K8n96z0vAHbktz37lTpat6z9e1ceyJ5aVWVq9rWOsVfnp/d0eiJds7lm@W2mCLHaEaOxDUkambkpAr6pjCjqaE7CLLsKEdYbmBEqw2DmNOha852FMBdrvlIHwQ1MCKdTNs4BfrQL5jBiTtoCSTRUHgJ@@wZLnFkhpCIsVwSwVtvLMAgBZK2j9WxfBlw5rtVnqLiURClbdQJYkkSeJfi1kzUR4YkUgzvKQyjBP2xXK28KXfQIIqJiffL6/maP7j9vLq6@0J2T9wg5ypa8TQJkL@xCqeoHheVdxUMUWxDOWN46YNlfDV2Ydzn6qQsswn61NKn5tLnxd9DGdz0K61EL4bHdU@Ddp5mr5oB6lAO/qX9k2rHhs0pR9DfdAuBq1P/9duuLK87z8228dBOxtmG/1T@2x@89c3zQZt/Dbti@FKvTZblg7aaPymTa/vy7a/uqPa@EXLjmg9VkS7aInD30Km@z8)

-82 bytes thanks to Shaggy!

Comment: A few quick golfs to get you down to [300 bytes](https://tio.run/##NZBLa8MwEITv/hUtBFkiyuLQm8Pah5JDoOSUQyEEIj8Vx7WEpD4g5Le7q5KedvZjZhZ2UF/K1@5iw2oyTTursXUBazN5M7Ywmj7pcA5Y3DwPYmN4gEqS@NaXseUaJx5kJkTkjQyoo0XcE4/cSSso5qBHW1qo8@Np4@ATLWMW9DM60LR7mj/H7ISYdilj6/aFYA0fylJ54bmWTog/5I0LnCtZUasCv6rA0yGF/Cr/4SM14FAOuaZbWDENTXGFhjEtkimao5UPmElFyxVqAg/ZRxmjVZnlE6G1EIlB3kkd6@NjeFd2y7Nc3Kj2np@XGqY8fdvtt0/b98Nu/3pIxTz/Ag)

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks, I had to add `+r.b` else it does not sort correctly by age.

Comment: [260](https://tio.run/##jdLPT9swFAfwe/6KLIdgD2OlsA6Syq22qQemiQNwmFRVws6PGqezI9tjTKV/e/ecNVxWBjm9b5z3yXtRFH/grrT3nT/Rpqp3fF1bzx7ZtDTamXVN12aFHo/v7nDUsJ1n001jLHLIY2KQp4J4PJFMI08yPMHhVkU8k3hiEN5GjiFLOsymlpbUGesR4kRA5lSdCKqIpSvWzZClP1lH5TtmqSQdLXGxWMKZguzeW3hL6P/BOyTZ1CFJLMY40gy1RBAFXEtX/TFn8IBi6ulJgshEKmkFh1WaStLuCY5xmqqZKsQsKzQQIxwZhhoiw1xhfdTMFhBhE0n1sjj6dnk1j@ffby@vvtwe4d0Dt7G3dR2zeBPFcCU6KeJkXlXcVgmJExnijee2DUlAOv14BlUVqjyHykGVkb/NJdSLvgzXZq9dGyGgOz6oXQzaWZY9a3tpGW/JP9pXo3ts0LT5FfJe@zBoffW6dsO1433/odnOB@10mG30X@2T/c1f3jQftPHbtM@Wa/3SbHk2aKPxmza9vi/b/tMd1MbPWn5A67FltI0aFP4WPNn9AQ)

Comment: I _think_ that works, at least; with so few test cases it's hard to tell.

Comment: [255](https://tio.run/##jdLPb9MwFAfwe/6KkENmg2elGwXS6rUC1MMQ2mHbAamqNDs/6iXFjmwzhrr@7eU5NLvQwXzJ98V@H/lFacS9cIW96/ypNmW1F5vKeniAWWG0M5uKb8yaPLy5vaVRDXsPs21tLHHEU2aI55J5OlWgiWcZndLwqmQeFJ0aQneRA2JZR2FmecGdsZ4QwSTWgrvXgstTiU@JiuVr6ObE8h/QcfUKLFes4wWdLFcs9H4XHVEwc0QxSymNNJCWSdYg1fJ1vy0ADzTQPD4qVECmipe4WaapYu2BEJSmKZ6Q82aiURjRyACpmQpXCpOTer7EEodQXK8mJ18vLhfx4tvNxeXnmxO6vxc29raqYoi3UYwr0ckkThZlKWyZsDhRobz2wrahklidvTvHVIaU55gcpoz9aS4wL/sY1vagXRkpsTs@qn0YtPMse9IO0iresb@0L0b32KBp8zPUB@3toPXp/9q10E70/cfu9n7Qzoa7jf6pfbS/xPOT5oM2fpn2yQqtn7tbng3aaPyiSa/uirb/dEe18ZOWH9F6bBXtopqEv4VO978B)

Comment: [248](https://tio.run/##jdJBT9swFAfwez6Fl0Owh3lKYR2klVNtUw9MEwfgMKmKhJ2kNUlnR7bHmEo/e2dnDZeVgS/@vyjvp/eiNPyB29Lcd@5E6are8XVtHHtkeamV1esa1nqFH4/v7ki0ZDvH8s1SG2yxI1RjB4I6MnVTEnJFHVPY0ZSQbWQZNrQjLDdQgtXGYcyp8DUH@56DOBH@Fr7fwIp1M2zgJ@tAvmMGJO2gJJNFQUPvD95hyXKLJTWEkEgx3FJBG08tAKCFkvbXqhhebVjz9CS9x0QiocpbqJJEkiTxj8WsmSgPjEikGV5SGSYKK2M5W/jSLyFBFZOjb5dXczT/fnt59eX2iOweuEHO1DViaBMhf2IVT1A8rypuqpiiWIbyxnHThkr46vTjmU9VSFnmk/UppX@bS58XfQxns9eutRC@Gx3ULgbtLE2ftb1UoC39R/uqVY8NmtK/Qr3XPgxan17XbriyvO8/NNv5oJ0Os43@q30yv/nLm2aDNn6b9tlwpV6aLUsHbTR@06bX92Xbf7qD2vhZyw5oPVZE22iJw99Cprs/)

Comment: @Shaggy, wow I should go back to golfing school :-)

Comment: PPCG _is_ golfing school! ;)

Comment: [244](https://tio.run/##jdJBT9swFAfwez6Fl0Owh3lKYR2klVNtUw9MEwfgMKmKhJ2kNUlnR7bHmEo/e2dnDZeVgS/@vyjvp/eiNPyB29Lcd@5E6are8XVtHHtkeamV1esa1nqFH4/v7ki0ZDvH8s1SG2yxI1RjB4I6MnVTEnJFHVPY0ZSQbWQZNrQjLDdQgtXGYcyp8DUH@56DOBH@Fr7fwIp1M2zgJ@tAvmMGJO2gJJNFQeAH77BkucWSGkIixXBLBW08swCAFkraX6tieLNhzdOT9BYTiYQqb6FKEkmSxD8Ws2aiPDAikWZ4SWWYJqyL5WzhS7@ABFVMjr5dXs3R/Pvt5dWX2yOye@AGOVPXiKFNhPyJVTxB8byquKliimIZyhvHTRsq4avTj2c@VSFlmU/Wp5T@bS59XvQxnM1eu9ZC@G50ULsYtLM0fdb2UoG29B/tq1Y9NmhK/wr1XvswaH16XbvhyvK@/9Bs54N2Osw2@q/2yfzmL2@aDdr4bdpnw5V6abYsHbTR@E2bXt@Xbf/pDmrjZy07oPVYEW2jJQ5/C5nu/gA)

Comment: nice! I was playing around with using `reduce` instead of sorting the arrays but did not get very far, do you think it could work?

Comment: or concatenating the siblings to the child array and sorting by bastard, relationship, sex, age.

Comment: I think [this](https://tio.run/##jdLPT8IwFAfw@/6KutOWbM0GTihmGE28eISj4fC6Hw7BPtIuGIP87bMtKxeH0ku/r8n75L2k77AHVcj1ro0FllVX5x3mc6QFVSjbIICIh/mc0@YmR9o8xOkMqIo5Vd9Aub55SD9gF9RhtwdJWllVJCcHj@jjC39G/OeyBFn6EfEbUy5bkBtTcV2N7sY6lSYxppPSKYlOzYXOrzaac@i1BXKuu8mgNnXaOEnOWi@tyDH6pb2gsJjTBH6autdunWbT/9oShALbPzTbxGkjN1v6p/Yov@Dypsxp2XXaYl1s7LJDGsuclrKrNn2SIMSlTVly1rIBzWIr7@jVgfktoVegULit6BbfTi/33Q8) might work for sorting by all 3 criteria simultaneously.

Comment: Actually, we'd need a logical OR rather than a bitwise one. And our current `sort` suffers from a similar bug; `a.s*a.b-b.s*b.b` needs to be `a.s-b.s||a.b-b.b`.